# How can I make a template function an argument to another template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, parameters, std-function

I have a class that holds various algorithms:

```
class Algorithm{

Algorithm()=delete;

public:
    template <typename IntegerType> 
    static IntegerType One(IntegerType a, IntegerType b);

    template <typename IntegerType> 
    static IntegerType Two(IntegerType a, IntegerType b);

    template <typename IntegerType> 
    static IntegerType Three(IntegerType a, IntegerType b);

    // ...
};
```

They can be called the following way:

```
int main(){

    Algorithm::One(35,68);
    Algorithm::Two(2344,65);
    //...
}
```

Now I want to make a function that will take any "Algorithm" function and perform the same steps before and after calling that function.
Here is what I have:

```
template <typename IntegerType>
void Run_Algorithm(std::function<IntegerType(IntegerType,IntegerType)>fun, IntegerType a, IntegerType b){
    //... stuff ...
    fun(a,b);
    //... stuff ...
    return;
}
```

When I try to call the function like this:

```
Run_Algorithm(Algorithm::One,1,1);
```

The error I get is:

```
cannot resolve overloaded function ‘One’ based on conversion to type ‘std::function<int(int, int)>’
```

**How can I go about setting up a generic routine, that takes the desired algorithm as a parameter?**

**EDIT:**
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18684726/908939) worked as desired.
It looks like this:

```
template <typename IntegerType>
void Run_Algorithm(IntegerType(*fun)(IntegerType, IntegerType), IntegerType a, IntegerType b){
    //... stuff ...
    fun(a,b);
    //... stuff ...
    return;
}
```

Comment: `Algorithm` looks like a `namespace`.

Comment: @MSalters I'd like it to be a namespace, but I don't want to allow access to certain sub-routines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of a function template, like `Algorithm::One`, is treated like the name of a set of overloaded functions here. To select one of the overloads from that set, you need to put that name in a context where a specific *function type* (signature) is required. This is not possible with `std::function`, as it can take any argument in its ctor (with some "callable" requirements).

Additionally, using `std::function` as a parameter type is not required and not useful if the function is a template. It would just add an unnecessary type erasure and a level of indirection. The standard idiom of passing functions is:

```
template <typename Fun, typename IntegerType>
void Run_Algorithm(Fun fun, IntegerType a, IntegerType b);
```

But this doesn't help you selecting one overload of the overload set. You could select the overload at call site, as [Dieter Lücking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2249683/dieter-lucking) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18684731/420683), and then use this idiom.

However, you can provide an overload/alternatively:

```
template < typename IntegerType >
void Run_Algorithm(IntegerType(*)(IntegerType, IntegerType),
                   IntegerType, IntegerType);
```

which is more specialized and therefore preferred, if possible. Here, the function type is strictly `IntegerType(IntegerType, IntegerType)`, therefore the compiler can select an overload of the overload set (from the name `Algorithm::One`).

<sub>*Note:* As per [temp.deduct.type]/5, `IntegerType` is in the first parameter in a non-deduced context for the argument `Algorithm::One`. Therefore, the second and third parameter are used to deduce `IntegerType`. After this deduction, the function type is fully specified and the overload can be selected.</sub>

The questions remain 1) if that's what you want and 2) if there's a better way to do what you intent to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need Algorithm::One< int > (not Algorithm::One) and thanks to ymett ([Why can't my C++ compiler deduce template argument for boost function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871044/why-cant-my-c-compiler-deduce-template-argument-for-boost-function)):

```
template <class T> struct identity { typedef T type; };

template <typename IntegerType>
void Run_Algorithm(
    typename identity<
        std::function<IntegerType(IntegerType,IntegerType)>>::type fun,
    IntegerType a,
    IntegerType b)
{
}

int main() {
    Run_Algorithm(Algorithm::One<int>,1,1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `identity` is to put `IntegerType` in a non-deduced context for the first parameter of `Run_Algorithm`; otherwise the compiler would try (and fail) to deduce `IntegerType` from the first argument passed. It fails because the first argument is not a `std::function` here.

Comment: If you disambiguate (select the overload) at call site, you could as well use another template parameter instead of `std::function` (like `template<class Fun, class Int> void Run_Algorithm(Fun, Int, Int);`)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
template <template <typename T> class IntegerType>
void Run_Algorithm // ...
```

Comment: Where would T get deduced?  I'm not sure what the parameter list would look like here.